# String value in Optional is overwrite

Tags: java, option-type

I've been working with Optional in Java. However, in one of my tests, I realized something odd had happened. When I execute the following code:

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class OptionalTest {
    static String globalString = "Hello";

    public static void main(String... optional) {
        String otherString = "Other";
        globalString += Optional.of(otherString)
            .orElse(updateString());
        System.out.println(globalString);
    }

    static String updateString() {
        System.out.println("It's called");
        globalString = "Not Hello";
        return "Another";
    }
}
```

I got the following result:

```
It's called
HelloOther
```

Instead of:

```
It's called
Not HelloOther
```

I can't figure out how if the `updateString()` method is called, the `globalString` has the same initial value when the Optional result is resolved.

Could someone explain this behavior? Thanx in advance.

Comment: maybe try reading javadoc for orElse? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-

Comment: @NathanHughes I don't think that's the question.

Comment: It's not clear why you expect `Not Hello`. Are you confused by how `+=` evaluates its operands?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think that's the question.

Comment: or maybe the question is how does the JVM  decide if the thing passed in is a Supplier?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry if I wasn't clear. I didn't expect ```Not Hello```. I just wondered how it work cuz the ```updateString()``` is called, however the ```globalString ``` "not change" at the end

Answer (score 3):

According to the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), this is what a compound assignment does at runtime. Relevant parts only (emphasis mine):

> If the left-hand operand expression is not an array access expression,
> then:
>
> - First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable.
> - **the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated.**
> - the saved value of the left-hand variable and the value of the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation indicated
>   by the compound assignment operator.
> - the result of the binary operation is converted to the type of the left-hand variable, and the result of the conversion is stored into
>   the variable.

As you can see, the value of `globalString` before calling `updateString` is saved first, and only then is the RHS evaluated. It is not: RHS is evaluates, and then `globalString` is evaluated to see what the result should be appended to.

In general, evaluation in Java happens left to right, so even if you use a simple assignment, it still would not be your expected output:

```
globalString = globalString + Optional.of(otherString)
    .orElse(updateString());
```

The second `globalString` is evaluated first. Then `updateString` is called, setting `globalString`. With both operands evaluated, `+` is evaluated to the string `HelloOther`, to which `globalString` is set to.

Answer (score 1):

The concat operation evaluates `globalString` before the update happens. Essentially, it translates to this:

```
String part1 = globalString; // Hello
String part2 = Optional.of(otherString).orElse(updateString()); // Other
globalString = part1 + part2; // HelloOther
```

What happens to inside `updateString()` has no effect on the end result.